# Usage frequency of windows application

Tags: windows, winapi, usage-statistics

I have a homepage need to count the usage frequency of Notepad or Calc application. Is there any Windows API that I can know the usage frequency of windows application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But you can write a service that will check applications in memory and do appropriate calculations. Few links:

- [Windows Services Programming](http://www.tenouk.com/ModuleDD.html)
- [Simple Windows Service Sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/simplewindowsservice.aspx)

Also, shell variant from bua is quite ready solution. You just need some parsing and updating the counter (not necessary in the database).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about one, but You could quite easily achieve that by:

ex:
using

> cmd.exe ->  tasklist

apply each 10 sec. (that would not load the CPU) - one good solution is to use python scheduler.

```
import sched, time
from subprocess import *
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def get_task():
    f=open("log",'wt')
    p=Popen("tasklist",stdout=f)
    p.terminate()
    p.close()

def analise_logs():
    # do some analise here

def print_some_times():
    while(1):
        print time.time()
        s.enter(5, 1, get_tasks, ())
        analise_logs()
        s.run()
```

do some awk (if you have cygwin), or powershell awk like processing on that file.

Count processes which interest you. Write result to another file with updated infos.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my answer to [How Do I Stop An Application From Opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284674/how-do-i-stop-an-application-from-opening#1285036) and use the same technique.  In essence when the application is launched your program is run and you can log any information that you require and then open the app.