# How to prevent starting TaskManager in my Desktop?

Tags: windows, winapi, desktop, taskmanager

I am creating a new Desktop in Windows XP/Vista and 7 using win32 API.
This is more like having a secure Desktop and I don't want let any other application to be executed in that Desktop.

Well, in Windows XP if I press strg+shift+Esc or strg+alt+ent, in the Desktop which I created, I don't see the task manger on my Desktop but instead on the Default Desktop.

Well, that's ok, but in Windows Vista, doing the same I get the task manager in my Desktop where the user can start another application using File->New task (Run...) menu.

Here is my question, what is the best way to prevent task manager to be displayed in the desktop which I created or even prevent starting it?

1) using the registry key,
2) capturing the key strokes?
3) what else???

Thanks in advance!
Gohlool

Comment: Do you want corporate security, or to prevent your child from defeating your net nanny?

Comment: See my solution to [how-do-i-stop-an-application-from-opening](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284674/how-do-i-stop-an-application-from-opening) This will work fine, I just
tested it.

Comment: Well, I don't get what you really mean, but for info, I am showing some information in my viewer and I don't want that any other software which can use the GetDC(0) call and draw on that DC over my Information to manipulate the information! That's it!

Comment: Is this a program you are destributing to other users?

Comment: Yes! The firm is distributing that software!

Comment: WOW! That's a nice one! Since it is a entry in HKEY_CURRENT_USER there is no need of Admin privileges. So I can call add the Registry entry as soon I switch the Desktop() make that entry and delete it again when I am ready with my work! I'll give a try!

Comment: Well, I checked your solution again and noticed I was wrong with HKEY_CURRENT_USER! Its HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE! Well, I already implemented a COM Elevation Moniker! can use that to access the Registry. Well, let see!

Answer (score 2):

Group Policy is your friend.  [Here's how to disable it](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/WindowsXP/UserTips/Customization/EnableDisableTaskManagerinWindowsXPHomePro.html).

Comment: Thanks! But I don't want to disable it for everybody or even for my Desktop! As I said, when I change the Desktop, at that point I want to prevent task manager to be executed or shown in my Desktop, which I created by CreateDesktop() call!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are calling [CreateDesktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682124(VS.85).aspx), if so, you should be able to lock down that desktop with a security descriptor that only allows access to your program

Comment: Exactly! I am using CreateDesktop() API CALL! Do you have any hint or sample how to define the security descriptor! I rried but failed!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the best solution, but you could always monitor for task manager and close it

```
foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses()) {
        if (clsProcess.ProcessName.StartsWith("taskmgr"))
        {
            clsProcess.Kill();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Code is in C#

Comment: Well, thanks for that tip. It's a fine idea! The Problem is that am I going to be fast enough to get the list of processes every let say 50 ms and check for the "taskmgr"? Well, I'll try that! Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

rename taskman.exe to somthing else.

Comment: That might be the easiest way, but it's probably not the best way.

Comment: Well, I am not sure if UAC will let me to change the file name! But thanks for the comment!