# Prevent application from opening

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing an app in C# to prevent some executable file from opening. My app will detect opening selected executable file and show message box to let user choose to run it or not.

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\notepad.exe]
"Debugger"="calc.exe"
```

I have use above method from [This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284674/how-do-i-stop-an-application-from-opening) but it will block all executable file with that name from any path. Which I want is to block only executable file in flashdrive or specifed path.

Example. I selected that my program will show message box when "a.exe" in Drive F:/ is opening. If I use a method in reference topic, it will block all "a.exe" in any path like "C:/a.exe", "D:/a.exe" or "F:/a.exe" but I want it to block only a.exe in F:/ not in other path or drive.

Any idea for this?

Thanks a lot.

#### Additional information:


Easy understanding with this question is...
I want my program to block some exe in specified path. When user try to open specified exe, my app will block it and have a message box to alert user. If user click "No", specify exe will not run but If user click "Yes", specify exe will run normally.

this will work like a anti virus software when user accidentally run virus file, Anti virus will block it and have some message to ask user that he still wanted to run it or not.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar point in a blog article where I try to detect the creation and destruction of a process instance. For this I use `ManagementEventWatcher` and this class uses queries like

```
internal ManagementEventWatcher WatchForProcessStart(string ProcessName)
{
    string Query = "SELECT TargetInstance" +
        " FROM __InstanceCreationEvent " + "WITHIN  2 " +
        " WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' " +
        " AND TargetInstance.Name = '" + ProcessName + "'";
    string Scope = "\\\\.\\root\\CIMV2";
    ManagementEventWatcher Watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(Scope, Query);
    Watcher.Start();
    return Watcher;
}
```

The scope is a `ManagementScope` instance which can be manipulated for your purposes as seen at MSDN

```
ManagementScope scope = 
        new ManagementScope(
        "\\\\FullComputerName\\root\\cimv2");
scope.Connect();
```

I hope this helps you a bit. More information

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementscope.aspx

http://www.idipous.net/how-to-monitor-proccess-creation-with-c/

Comment: I have try this and I found that this method only monitor selected process but cannot stop it before starting. I also try to use Process.Kill() but it will kill process after process start and already done some function.